# Parsing Json in Python Null data

Tags: python, json, pandas, null

Suppose I have the following two Json.

```
a={"id": "TUxNQkFHVUNBTTA0",
  "name": "Campestre 1a. Secc.",
  "city": {
    "id": "TUxNQ0FHVTk2NjY",
    "name": "Aguascalientes"
  },
  "state": {
    "id": "TUxNUEFHVTMwNjE",
    "name": "Aguascalientes"
  },
  "country": {
    "id": "MX",
    "name": "Mexico"
  },
  "geo_information": None,
  "subneighborhoods": [
  ]
}

b={
  "id": "TUxNTUxNQkFHVTNOSg",
  "name": "Aeropuerto Aguascalientes (Lic. Jesus Teran Peredo)",
  "city": {
    "id": "TUxNQ0FHVTk2NjY",
    "name": "Aguascalientes"
  },
  "state": {
    "id": "TUxNUEFHVTMwNjE",
    "name": "Aguascalientes"
  },
  "country": {
    "id": "MX",
    "name": "Mexico"
  },
  "geo_information": {
    "location": {
      "latitude": 21.701155,
      "longitude": -102.31439
    }
  },
  "subneighborhoods": [
  ]
}


print b
```

and I want to create a table 'locations' with the next columns:

locations = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['city_id', 'city_name', 'name',             'latitud', 'longitud', 'country_id', 'country_name', 'state_id', 'state_name', 'subneighborhoods', 'id'])

Expect to have the following data:

I expect to have the following table

```
TUxNQkFHVUNBTTA0, Campestre 1a. Secc., TUxNQ0FHVTk2NjY, Aguascalientes, TUxNUEFHVTMwNjE, Aguascalientes, MX, Mexico, Null, Null, []
TUxNTUxNQkFHVTNOSg, Aeropuerto Aguascalientes (Lic. Jesus Teran Peredo), TUxNQ0FHVTk2NjY, Aguascalientes, TUxNUEFHVTMwNjE, Aguascalientes, MX, Mexico, 21.701155,  -102.31439, []
```

As in 'a' the geo_information is None, I can not create the table.
How con I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not `json`, those are dictionaries. They can easily be serialized into json with `json.dumps(a)`.

Comment: @jordanm that is true, but given that the question asks about putting the data into a `pandas.DataFrame`, I suspect the OP does *not* want to serialize the dictionaries.

Comment: `subneighborhoods` is a list, how does the data in it looks like? What do you expect the relevant column in locations to contain?

Comment: I expect to have the following table

city_id, city_name, name, latitud, longitud, country_id, country_name, state_id, state_name, subneighborhoods
TUxNQkFHVUNBTTA0, Campestre 1a. Secc., TUxNQ0FHVTk2NjY, Aguascalientes, TUxNUEFHVTMwNjE, Aguascalientes, MX, Mexico, Null, Null, []
TUxNTUxNQkFHVTNOSg, Aeropuerto Aguascalientes (Lic. Jesus Teran Peredo), TUxNQ0FHVTk2NjY, Aguascalientes, TUxNUEFHVTMwNjE, Aguascalientes, MX, Mexico, 21.701155,  -102.31439, []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `json_normalizer`? It will do what you request, just with a dot instead of underline.

```
In[1]: from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

In[2]: pd.DataFrame(json_normalize([a,b]))
Out[2]: 
           city.id       city.name country.id country.name  geo_information  \
0  TUxNQ0FHVTk2NjY  Aguascalientes         MX       Mexico              NaN
1  TUxNQ0FHVTk2NjY  Aguascalientes         MX       Mexico              NaN

   geo_information.location.latitude  geo_information.location.longitude  \
0                                NaN                                 NaN
1                          21.701155                          -102.31439

                   id                                               name  \
0    TUxNQkFHVUNBTTA0                                Campestre 1a. Secc.
1  TUxNTUxNQkFHVTNOSg  Aeropuerto Aguascalientes (Lic. Jesus Teran Pe...

          state.id      state.name subneighborhoods
0  TUxNUEFHVTMwNjE  Aguascalientes               []
1  TUxNUEFHVTMwNjE  Aguascalientes               []
```

(However, it will leave `subneighborhoods` intact, which is not necessarily what you want)

Comment: It was solved by         if tree_json['geo_information'] is None:
            tree_json.update({"geo_information": {"location": {"latitude": None, "longitude": None}}})